# How can I get a struct pointer from a slice in golang

Tags: pointers, go, struct, slice

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type demo struct {
     name string
}

func main() {
     demo_slice := make([]demo, 3)
     demo_slice[0] = demo{"str1"}
     demo_slice[1] = demo{"str2"}
     demo_slice[2] = demo{"str3"}

     point_demo_slice := make([]*demo, 3)
     for index, value := range demo_slice {
          fmt.Printf("\n%v==++++++++++++++%p\n", value, &value)
          point_demo_slice[index] = &value
     }
}
```

The result:

```
{str1}==++++++++++++++0x20818a220

{str2}==++++++++++++++0x20818a220

{str3}==++++++++++++++0x20818a220
```

`0x20818a220` is the last element's pointer value.

Why are all the pointer values ​​the same?

How can I get those right pointer values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not referring to the elements of the slice but the local `value` variable:

```
fmt.Printf("\n%v==++++++++++++++%p\n", value, &value)
```

Hence all the pointer values will be the same (the address of local variable `value`). If you want pointers to the elements of the slice, then take the address of the appropriate element:

```
fmt.Printf("\n%v==++++++++++++++%p\n", demo_slice[index], &demo_slice[index])
```

This will produce the following output, all pointers are different:

```
{str1}==++++++++++++++0x104342e0

{str2}==++++++++++++++0x104342e8

{str3}==++++++++++++++0x104342f0
```